# HTML input type="hidden" is not binding the right values in foreach loop

Tags: html, pike

I'm programming in a language called pike, which is an interpreted, object-oriented, dynamic programming language with a syntax similar to C. The pike code is used to generate HTML and javascript.

Now to my problem. I have a form called formularet and a submit button for each language. What I want to do is pass the language `lang` as an argument when the form is submitted. I thought this could be achieved by using a hidden input, but whenever any submit button is pressed, `lang` is set to *all* the languages instead of just the one which button was pressed. This is basically the relevent code (languageOrder is an array with all the languages):

```
res+= "<form name=\"formularet\" action=right.html method="POST">"

foreach(languageOrder, string lang) {
    res+= "<input type=hidden name=lang value=\""+lang+"\">\n"
      "<input type=submit name=a2 value=\"Save\">&nbsp;"
}
```

Any ideas on how to just pass the language for the button that was pressed?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping form tags around all of the buttons (doing so in the foreach loop) - so you have lots of forms rather than them all in the one form? Otherwise when you submit the main form all data gets posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between the button and the hidden input.

If you want to send specific data for a particular submit button, then encode that data into the submit button:

```
<button name="lang" value="en">Save</button>
```

Comment: But the submit button already has a value. I've thought about adding the language to the value like: `"<input type=submit name=a2 value=\""+lang+" Save\">&nbsp;"` But I'd rather have it as 2 separate variables. Is that possible?